# Where are the bookmarked question votes on this new user profile styling?

Tags: bug, profile-page

I've noticed that the Stack Overflow user profile has new styling. However, as you can see in the screenshot, along with the other text like `0 answers` and `29 views`, there's `votes` too; but that's all there is. I know this specific question has no votes, but even the questions that do have votes don't show it. It's just `votes`. And I know that it's not just a display issue in my browser, because if I inspect that element it shows this:

```html
<div class="s-post-summary--stats-item">votes</div>
```

while the others look like this:

```html
<div class="s-post-summary--stats-item">29 views</div>
```

This isn't top-priority, but I think that if we're going to have a new profile arrangement than we should be able to view the same things we could before.

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: Seems like one for https://meta.stackexchange.com since it should apply to all SE sites, not just Stack Overflow.

Comment: Network-wide issues can still be posted here, @kaya3

Comment: Already reported: [New responsive Activity page](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/372597/289905).